# Make Node.js app port not accessible on other domains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, node.js

I have a server with Parallels Plesk as Server Control Panel, apache2 (with mod_proxy and mod_http_proxy), nginx and Node.js installed. On this server I have multiple domains and subdomains, but only one IP.

If I start a node-app on e.g. port `1337` it will be global accessible on all domains and subdomains on this server/IP with this port. (`domainA.com:1337`, `sub.domainA.com:1337`, `domainB:1337`)

Via Plesk I can change the apache2 vhost.conf for `domainA.com`. I can use following code to route port 80 to port 1337 for `domainA.com`: (I'd rather use nginx but the settings in Plesk to adjust nginx quick are somehow limited)

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Yaay, I can access my node-app running on Port 1337 through Port 80 on `domainA.com`!

BUT: Port 1337 is still directly accessible on all domains on my Server. Not only `domainA.com:1337` shows me my node-app, `sub.domainA.com:1337` and `domainB.com:1337` will show my app, too.

It's total logical why this port is still accessible everywhere, but how can I "block" this port on these other domains?

Best case scenario would be that `domainA.com:1337` redirects to `domainA.com` and `sub.domainA.com:1337` / `domainB.com:1337` won't show anything.

Is this somehow possible with my setup?

If it's possible with nginx instead of apache – why not! I only used apache's mod_proxy because it was way easier to setup in Plesk.

Comment: The simplest way is to make your node app listen only to localhost so it will not be reachable from outside the box.

Comment: Thanks, but the app listens only to localhost. If it could only listen to a virtual host, would this be possible or rather is this possible?

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: The Node App is listening only to localhost, that's the default behaviour. My thoughts were: If it could listen to a host other than localhost and the domain (the domain I want to run the app on) will resolve to this host it could work in theory. I don't know if this is actually possible to do. I'm not searching for a complex solution to go through one time – I'm trying to find a simple and easy-to-set-up way for every node app I deploy on my Server. My setup isn't that special. An easy solution would be a benefit for a lot of people.

Comment: If by default you mean `.listen(1337)` you're wrong. «If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address (INADDR_ANY).»

Comment: All `hostname` in `.listen()` does is resolving the hostname to a IP address. Since I have only one IP Address (as I wrote) this won't help.

Comment: You have at least two addresses. One external like `1.2.3.4`, and one local `127.0.0.1`. Second address is not reachable from outside the same machine. So `.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1')` will make node unreacheble from other machines, but Apache will still have access via localhost:1337

Comment: That totally works, thanks! Sorry – I thought if something runs on localhost it's accessible from the external IP, too.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yeah, I said I'm working with Plesk, but if you read the comments of Alexey you will see that it has nothing to do with Plesk itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesk now has seamless Node.JS support - and its hosting, subscription etc. compatible.  http://ext.plesk.com/packages/28f799af-1ff4-4bb8-9c87-a04f0f23d32e-jxcore-support